# Unable to yum install PDO in PHP 7 (conflict)

Tags: php, pdo, centos, yum

I just successfully installed the new PHP 7 on my Centos 7 server.
However I cannot manage to install PDO. When I update yum and then run `yum install php-pdo` I get the below output.

Does php-pdo require a PHP lower than 5.5?

PHP 5 was previously installed on my server but I removed it with all of its packages.

How do I resolve this issue?

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.denit.net
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: mirror.denit.net
 * updates: mirror.denit.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1 for package: php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.0-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem now, I could install all php 7 compliant packages by preceding it with 'php70w' such as

```
yum install php70w-mbstring php70w-json php70w-gd php70w-mcrypt
```